I forgot to remove all authors' names from the appendix for a double-blind journal submission. What are the potential consequences?
I submitted a paper to a double-blind peer-reviewed journal. Unfortunately, I noticed that we forgot to remove the authors' names from the appendix. The submission was very recent, and until now, only the editor has seen the paper and the appendix. I'm panicking a bit right now. What should I expect? Is this a reason to automatically reject the paper, or would a typical editor simply ask me to correct the appendix and resubmit the paper?
Thank you for your answers!

For situations like this, especially in case of panic, it helps to remember that a journal wants to publish good papers.  That's the entire point of a journal.  So they have every incentive to work with you and let you correct this.  Think from the editor's perspective: wouldn't it be foolish of them to reject a potentially great paper for a purely technical issue like this, which can be fixed with practically no effort on their part?

In a journal without fixed deadlines, you may just ask them to correct it. Do so ASAP. In a conference, that may be an outright desk reject without option for appeal, depending on the importance and volume that the conference has.

Most editors will find this understandable. Your best bet is to contact the editor ASAP and explain the situation and give them a copy with the relevant redactions.

Anecdata:  My first or second paper (conference venue) I forgot to remove our names from the title page.  They caught it and asked me to submit correctly, please-and-thank-you.  No harm, no foul.  Other than mild embarrassment.
